# Open a hidden JavaScript form when linked from a different page

Tags: javascript, php, validation, show-hide

I don't know if there is an answer for this question, but i'll try to explain it and hope someone is smart enough to help me :).

**All right:**

For school I have an website where you can log in and register etc. On my index there is the log in and register form included, but hidden with JavaScript. By pressing a button you'll be able to login or register (One of the forms will appear). But the problem: I'm checking the register form with php on a different page, and the errors are outputted in a form on that page.

But, when you go back to the register/login page, it is hidden, ofcourse, and all the input is gone from the user and they have to retype everything. This `<? if(isset($_POST['example'])){echo htmlentities ($_POST['example']);} ?>` in my form doesn't work anymore. Putting the code from the other page in my index doesn't seem to be an option.

Thanks in advance for your response,

Paul

EDIT - 
I'll post some code to make it clearer. The javascript to hide and toggle:

`'$(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#login").hide();
                    $("#registerincl").hide();
                    $("#loginb").click(function(){
                        $("#login").toggle();
                        $("#loginb").hide();
                        $("#guest").hide();
                        $("#registerincl").hide();
                        $("#register").hide();
                        $("#hh").hide();
                    });
                    $("#register").click(function(){
                        $("#registerincl").toggle();
                        $("#register").hide();
                        $("#loginb").hide();
                        $("#guest").hide();
                        $("#hh").hide();
                        $("hr").hide();
                    }); 
                    $('#guest').click(function() {
                        window.location='guest.php';
                    });
                });'`

Ofcourse the link to my register validation page:

```
<form action="/register" method="post" target="">
```

And some of the php code

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
echo 'Je bent geregistreerd. Ga naar je email en activeer je account!';
} else {
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $register_data = array(
        'username'      => $_POST['username'],
        'joined'        => $_POST[$time],
        'password'      => $_POST['password'],
        'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'],
        'email'         => $_POST['email'],
        'email_code'    => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime())
    );
           register_user($register_data);
    header('Location: register.php?success');
    exit();

} else if (empty($errors) === false) {
    //echo output_errors($errors);
            }



<form action="/register.php" method="post">
        <ul class="login">
            <li>
                <h1>We konden je niet registreren!</h1>
                <?php
                    echo output_errors($errors);
                }
                ?>
            </li>
            <li>
                <br><br><br><a href="index">Probeer opnieuw</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

Comment: 1. You should probably post more of your code in order to get **exact** answers. 2. On the 2nd page where you handle errors, you could put the values the user provided into $_SESSION variables. In your form you just put the $_SESSION values into the input fields then.

Comment: Use AJAX to send the request to your PHP, it should then provide the appropriate response object which you can render on the page whilst maintaining the form values

Comment: Yoda's approach would be alot cleaner and more professional - but probably you will have to re-write a lot of your code.

Comment: Do you have jQuery available or the ability to add it to this project? Ugh, I hate to write that, it will be a quick way to thrash this out if you do though.

Comment: @Yoda That sounds like a good idea, but how do i do that? :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to build your form without the action, leaving the fields as they already are.

With jQuery you should add an event handler to the form submit which prevents the default action then proceeds to grab the form data and AJAX it to your PHP class which deals with registration. You can then handle the success and error events and do what you need to do with the returned data. The link below explains how to reply to your javascript from php with JSON data.

Here is a sample AJAX request with an event handler so you can see what I'm talking about above. You can find a nice and comprehensive tutorial [here](http://www.lennu.net/2012/06/25/jquery-ajax-example-with-json-response/)

```
$(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    // validate and process form here
  });
});

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "bin/process.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
    .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
      $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It took me some time to figure it out but this actually worked! great site, thnx for the help